# Setting up freeRadius accounting

Tags: freeradius

I'm completely new to this.
My accounting data only update when the user disconnect i want to know how to set up a acct-interim-interval to harvest the acct data without needing to disconnect my users.
I have like 2k users
How do i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your radgroupreply table:

Add a row

ID: Auto increment

groupname: Name of the group that you want to monitor (use accounting without disconnecting users)

attribule: Acct-Interim-Interval

op: := (Note-> it's := not = not == just :=)

value: Time in seconds of your updates (Default is 60 or 120 secs i guess)

PS: You also need to enable Accouting inside your mikroktik.
Go to PPP menu -> Secrets -> PPP Authentiction&Accouting and select Accounting -> Select Use Radius and Accounting

Now you are ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like acct-interim-interval is not set when the user is authenticated. Most of the cases acct-interim-interval is 180 seconds that means Freeradius is receiving accounting request of every user in 180 seconds and not required to user logout.

Which captive portal you are using? Captive portal send acct-interim-interval or u can configure it in Freeradius default configuration file.

Comment: How do i configure it in my default conf file?
i don't know which captive portal is being used.

Comment: Which router are you using?  OpenWrt base or Mikrotik base?

Comment: Mikrotik base...
I add the line to my radgroupreply table.
Testing it right now to see if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IP > Hotspot > Server Profiles >

Double click on your profile and then select RADIUS tab, under this tab you'll find Accounting option just tick it and you'll find Interim update underneath you can enter any value but recommended value is between 00:01:00 to 00:09:00.

Comment: Not using Hotspot.
I'm using PPPoE

Comment: In this case goto PPP > Secrets > PPP Authendication & Accounting

Select Accounting and you'll find Interim update underneath you can enter any value but recommended value is between 00:01:00 to 00:09:00.

Comment: Did it adding a line to my DB radgroupreply, i have over 800 MK in my network.
Inserting it one by one would be a pain in the ass

Comment: Follow my earlier solution to you "Goto PPP > Secrets > PPP Authendication & Accounting" if you select that then you no need to add the records in radreply or radgroupreply. FYI. It will not add any records in your database.

Comment: As i said
I have over 800 Mikrotiks inside my network. This way is kinda easier for me